# How can I return array nested in multiple objects?

Tags: php, arrays, object

In PHP I am trying to list a specific array (devices) which is nested under 3 objects (return, user, associatedDevices).  I have my code as follows from the following [link](https://developer.cisco.com/docs/axl/#!php-quickstart/specifying-name-and-returnedtags).  Here is the following code:

```
$payload = array(
    "userid"=>$_POST["iduser"],
    "returnedTags"=>array(
        "device"=>"",
    )
);

$response = $client->getUser($payload);
```

A var_dump outputs the following:

```
    object(stdClass)#2 (1) { 
        ["return"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (1) { 
            ["user"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (1) { 
                ["uuid"]=> string(38) "{ECBF3CAC-672B-B205-D14F-DAB3A3805F60}" 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

When I do not filter the output I am able to see all information and grab the device array.

```
    object(stdClass)#2 (1) { 
        ["return"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (1) { 
            ["user"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (59) { 
                ["firstName"]=> string(5) "fname" 
                ["displayName"]=> string(5) "dname" 
                ["middleName"]=> string(0) "" 
                ["lastName"]=> string(5) "lname" 
                ["userid"]=> string(7) "user_id" 
                ["password"]=> string(0) "" 
                ["pin"]=> string(0) "" 
                ["mailid"]=> string(0) "" 
                ["department"]=> string(20) "IT Operations (AMER)" 
                ["manager"]=> string(0) "" 
                ["userLocale"]=> string(0) "" 
                ["associatedDevices"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (1) { 
                    **["device"]=> array(2) { 
                        [0]=> string(15) "SEP3863BBB68D5D" 
                        [1]=> string(15) "SEP5065F3B9AB95"** 
                        } 
                }
```

I assume there is a way to call that specific array, however am not seeing it.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Why key you want to retrieve? The `device` one?

Comment: I am trying to only return the "device" strings.

Comment: Are the number of levels deep dynamic or static ?

Comment: The path to the array is static, however the number of entries in the device array can vary.

Comment: try this: `$payload = array("userid"=>$_POST["iduser"],"returnedTags"=>array("associatedDevices","device"));$response = $client->getUser($payload);` and then check you get your data in `associatedDevices` or `device` section. Remove the other one which didn't give you response and kept the one which gives you your desired result

Answer (score 0):

Say `$obj` is your stdClass object, you would access the `device` array as below, where you access each object from it's parent object's property.

```
$devices = $obj->return->user->associatedDevices->device;
print_r($devices);
```

---

To get data from your initial payload array, you need to access `returnedTags` and then `device` inside of it, like below,

```
$devices = $payload['returnedTags']['device'];
```

Comment: Thank you for this, however I am still not understanding where this fits into the "returnedTags" key.  Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Chad Where is returnedTags in your collection of whole data?

Comment: $payload = array(
       "userid"=>$_POST["iduser"],
       "returnedTags"=>array("device"=>"",
                       )
                   );


    $response = $client->getUser($payload);

Comment: Apologies, however I am still unable to get this working.  Where exactly am I defining $devices?  Inside the payload array?

Comment: @Chad no outside of it. It's a global variable for its scope.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225539/discussion-between-chad-and-nice-dev).